# DLL loaded across processes - how to make certain actions "singleton-like"

Tags: c++, windows, dll, shared-libraries, shared-memory

## Background

I'm developing a `C++` windows app.

My app will open number of processes. Each process will load a `Logger DLL` that provides an interface to register log events and decide when and how to flush logs to a file.

[image]

## Problem

Say that I define a simple decision to be made in the `Logger DLL`: every time a 100 log events were registered, flush them to a file.

How do I make sure the flush is performed only once by only one instance of the DLL?

What is best-practice approach for cases when a DLL is shared across processes and one of its actions need to be performed only once across processes?

## Notes

It is crucial that we define a shared memory. Each process needs to be aware of other processes log events. So, we can't have each DLL instance stores its own logs and flush them separately.

Comment: You must already be protecting the memory access, presumably using a mutex object.  Can't that same mechanism protect the decision to flush the cached events?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes. it can _protect the decision to flush the cached events_ **at the same time**, however, how will the other DLL instances know that one of them already made this decision in the past. I guess you could say that it doesn't matter because the same logic is implement in every instance. So, just as there is no risk that a single instance will make the same "job" twice, there is no risk of multiple instances performing the same "job" twice

Comment: Typically, if flushing the events to the file doesn't actually remove them from the shared memory, one of the variables stored in the shared memory would be keeping track of which events have already been written.  You must need *something* like this even if only one DLL is present, how do you currently figure out which events to write?

Comment: Could you please clarify the last paragraph of your question, since there has been some debate about it.  Is it an actual requirement that process A must to be able to see the content of events from process B?  Or did you just think that would make it easier to write the events to a file?

Comment: Say `process 1` wants to fetch the last 50 log events from `Logger DLL`, then `Logger DLL` must return the last 50 log event from **all the processes** that had registered events to it. I wanted to clarify that some sort of "shared memory" is essential.

Comment: Does the first or second or any process *really* has to fetch events already logged, or is it just required that ***someone*, somehow** flush them out once logged, and that someone may be a separate logging server process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it very clear what the logging architecture is, e.g., are the events appended to the file, or is a new file written each time?  When you write events to the file, are they removed from the shared memory?

In most cases, you would already be tracking (one way or another) which events have been written and which still need to be written, so deciding whether there are a hundred events pending is trivial.  You just need to put this information in the shared memory block, and access it with the appropriate synchronization barriers.

However, to address your question as posed:

> Say that I define a simple decision to be made in the Logger DLL: every time a 100 log events were registered, flush them to a file.

You can do this with a simple counter, in shared memory of course.  If for some reason you can't put this in the existing shared memory block, you can create a separate one.

---

If you're already protected by a mutex, this is as simple as:

```
void count_new_event()
{
    if ((*counter)++ == 100) 
    {
       flush_events();
       (*counter) = 0;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to avoid claiming the mutex, you could instead do something like this:

```
void count_new_event()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD count = InterlockedCompareExchange(counter, 0, 99);
        if (count == 99)
        {
            // The count was 99, so this is the 100th call
            // The call to InterlockedCompareExchange reset the counter
            flush_events();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (InterlockedCompareExchange(counter, count + 1, count) == count)
            {
                // We've successfully incremented the counter
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Oops, someone got in before us; try again
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code, and it isn't necessarily the most efficient possible approach either.  But it should work in most scenarios, and will be more efficient than claiming the mutex if you don't already have it.

Note also I'm assuming that `flush_events` will deal with the scenario where calls to it from different processes overlap.  That might be as simple as having it claim the mutex.  If not, e.g., if flushing a hundred events at a time might not be efficient enough to keep up with the rate of new events, you would almost certainly be better off tracking which events need to be written.

---

You can do something similar if you want to flush the log periodically, say once a minute, rather than every hundred events.  Just record the timestamp of the last flush in shared memory and compare it to the current time.  If you don't want to claim the mutex, you can use `InterlockedCompareExchange` to update the timestamp; the call to `InterlockedCompareExchange` will succeed in exactly one process, so that's the one that does the flush.

Comment: How do you share the events? I know how to put a DWORD in a shared memory region but how do I put an `std::vector<Event>`'s (or `std::vector<std::wstring>` if your prefer) backing store to be in said shared memory? Placement new of the vector itself doesn't help here and neither does anything of the Sort even a custom a locator can't to that. Your solution forces OF to manage data by hand, manually. I prefer the IPC. Optimizing sometimes that doesn't bother anyone and paying for it by sharing a byte array on top of which OP had to force structure and meaning... Not so great.

Comment: @conio, the question explicitly specifies that the events must be stored in shared memory, and it sounds to me as if that part is already done.  The OP might or might not have had good reasons for that decision, but it wasn't part of the question.  (But since he has to serialize the data either way, is there really any advantage to sending it over a pipe or socket versus putting it in stored memory?)

Comment: Reread the notes. The state has to be shared *in the sense that there should be only one* (that's the singleton from the title). It can sit in a shared memory between the logging processes, or in the logging server process in an architecture like dmi suggested, or in the Astral plane. The requirement is flush every 100 events from all sources combined (and obviously don't lose events and don't write the same event more than once). There is no requirement for one process to be able to read log messages by other processes, even if it's a side effect of one possible implementation of the...

Comment: ... actual requirements, only that the flush indeed happens. It isn't stated that this mustn't be done by a server process or that there mustn't be an extra process. If it were you'd use that argument in your comment to dmi rather than speaking about performance.

Comment: @conio, see the OP's response to my request for clarification.  They say the DLL does need to be able to query the log entries from the other processes, apparently it has to be able to provide this information to the client applications.

Comment: You asked a leading question and even then got the answer you want only by ignoring half of it. Why did OP write *I wanted to clarify that some sort of "shared memory" is essential* with quotes around "shared memory"? What do you think they mean? Why did he say "some sort of"? How many sorts of shared memory you're familiar with?

Comment: @conio, that's an awfully big leap to take on the strength of a couple of quote marks, particularly when it contradicts the rest of the sentence.  My interpretation of the quote marks is simply that they mean the OP isn't wedded to using any particular technology, *provided* any proposed alternative allows the processes to see one another's events.  But there's no point in arguing about it, we'll see how the OP responds to your variant of my question.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to set up something like following:

1. A log manager is introduced (it can be a dedicated standalone process). His role is:

   - provide a listening socket
   - time management
   - register/unregister clients
   - manages which exactly instance can flush logs to the logfile.
2. Every DLL instance:

   - has own buffers for logs
   - connects to the Manager's socket (registers itself)
   - receives commands from the manager to flush buffers.
   - upon a trigger receiving, appends own data to the logfile and informs the manager the job is done.

Instead of sockets, you can use shared memory (or another API) as well. I find personally sockets more convenient.

Comment: in this design, how can a `Process 1` "see" log events register via `Process 2`?

Comment: Process 2 connects to Process 1 and waits for a command to flush. Once a command is received, Process 2 opens the logfile and writes all internal buffers over to there, and sends to the Process 1 a response. Then Process 1 gives a 'start' command to the next process (i.e. Process 3)

Comment: Why do the processes in my app needs to be aware of one another? They should only know the logger DLL. Overcoming the issue by shifting Logger responsibility to the processes is not ideal. WDYT?

Comment: It was a proposal based on a typical design in such case. You can also implement a kind of a singleton pattern within the DLL using shared memory for this, but in my opinion this will much increase the complexity.

Comment: Fully-fledged IPC is significantly *more* complicated, as well as less efficient, than using shared memory and simple synchronization objects.  You need a message protocol, a separate listening thread or asynchronous I/O handling, some sort of infrastructure to launch the manager exactly once ... my answer solves the OPs problem as stated in three lines of code, or five if you count claiming and releasing the mutex. :-)